# Hibernate: Defining type mapping project-wide

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate & Joda Time, with support from the UserType library.

I'm able to persist my dates using the following approach:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
@Column
private DateTime startDate;
```

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to define this mapping once somewhere, rather than on every instance of the `DateTime` type.

Having had to swap out from JodaTime Hibernate to UserType when migrating from Hibernate 3.4 -> 4.0, I'm reluctant to have type declarations littered throughout the domain model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the 3.0.0.CR1 release of Usertype you can take advantage of autoregistration of the following types:

```
PersistentBigMoneyAmount
PersistentMoneyAmount
PersistentCurrency
PersistentCurrencyUnit
PersistentDateTime
PersistentDurationAsString
PersistentInstantAsTimestamp
PersistentLocalDate
PersistentLocalTime
PersistentMonthDayAsString
PersistentPeriodAsString
PersistentTimeOfDay
PersistentYearMonthDay
PersistentYears
```

To enable this feature, you need to set the JPA or Hibernate property 'jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes' to 'true'.

When upgrading the usertype.joda Maven artifact is now called 'usertype.core'.

More information is here http://blog.jadira.co.uk/blog/2012/1/19/release-jadira-usertype-300cr1-with-support-for-joda-money-0.html

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `BasicType`, and register it when building the `SessionFactory`. The hibernate reference manual explains this in [section 6.4.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom-type).